# PostGIS ERROR: operator does not exist: postgis.geometry @ geometry

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have had PostgreSQL `9.3.1` and PostGIS `2.1.0` installed (via https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/releases/tag/9.3.1.1-RC1) and working on my laptop for some time, and have been doing Ruby (`2.0.0`) on Rails (`4.0.0`) development with them.

I was able to successfully run typical operations, for example using [@](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Geometry_Contained.html) to determine whether a point (`postgis.geometry(Point,3785)`) is in a bounding box. Most recently I took the *exact* points and query I was successfully running in dev and made an equivalent feature test. This is when I began noticing issues...

Whereas a point on the *dev* side was stored like this (SRID `3785`):

```
POINT (-13740247.269752283 6126532.67447704)
```

...the *test* side saw it like this:

```
POINT (-8238307.241152702 4970299.628630948)
```

I wanted to post a Stack Overflow question about the issue, so I wanted the exact DB version. Whereas `select postgis_full_version();` previously worked (it's still in my Terminal scrollback history), now it was returning `ERROR:  function postgis_full_version() does not exist`. At that point I didn't think to check the `search_path`, and instead I followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/8459682 -- first I tried `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` but got `ERROR:  extension "postgis" already exists` -- and then I executed:

```
psql -d myapp_dev -f /Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/share/postgresql/contrib/postgis-2.1/postgis.sql
psql -d myapp_dev -f /Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/share/postgresql/contrib/postgis-2.1/spatial_ref_sys.sql
psql -d myapp_dev -f /Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/share/postgresql/contrib/postgis-2.1/postgis_comments.sql
```

Unfortunately those did not do the trick, and worse, now when I run my usual query I am seeing:

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: operator does not exist: postgis.geometry @ geometry
```

How could things go so wrong? I have not yet reset my computer. I only tried restarting PostgreSQL so far. Any ideas? Thank you for reading.

Comment: `SHOW search_path` and `\dt *.geometry` please.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment and answer. A few hours before you responded to my question, I was at my wits' end and I dropped my dev database. That didn't help, so I also dropped the `postgis` extension (`drop extension postgis cascade;`). After `bundle exec rake db:create`, `bundle exec rake db:gis:setup`, and `bundle exec rake db:migrate`, I was able to run my queries again. Sadly, I am unable to try what you suggested, though I can give you a partial idea from my Terminal scrollback history: `\dT geometry` had returned just `public`. Unfortunately I never executed `dT *.geometry`...

Comment: I am piecing this together from my Terminal scrollback history. When I started having problems with my *test* db, I quit `psql` and started it up again. At that point `show search_path;` returned just `public` (I don't yet know how to keep the `search_path` fixed for a given DB). Anyway, the error that emerged was `ERROR:  type "geometry" does not exist`. I am sure that, as you suggest, the problem was related to `search_path` and conflicts with PostGIS installs.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like you have PostGIS installed in your database more than once, possibly once via `CREATE EXTENSION` and again via a load script, or from a dump.

The hint is that:

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: operator does not exist: postgis.geometry @ geometry
```

mentions the schema qualifier `postgis.geometry` for one operand, and omits it for another. I'd say you have two copies of the the `geometry` type in different schemas, probably `public` and `postgis`.